# jq not writing value of variable but the actual text of the variable name

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm scripting in bash to edit a json template to replace some field values with arguments to my script, and trying to use jq to do the editing. My code is not replacing the --arg with the value of the argument, but the literal text of the argument name.

My template contains:

```
{
"name":""
}
```

My jq code:

```
jq --arg ad "192.168.5.5" -r '.name = "Addr $ad"' address.tmpl
```

This outputs:

```
{
    "name": "Addr $ad"
}
```

Or, if I remove the double-quotes

```
jq --arg ad "192.168.5.5" -r '.name = Addr $ad' address.tmpl
```

I get

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.name = Addr $ad
jq: 1 compile error
```

According to all that I have read, this should work. What am I doing wrong/how do I fix this????

OS = debian 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq --arg ad 192.168.5.5 -r '.name = "Addr " + $ad' address.tmpl
```

`$ad` will be expanded by the shell if it is not not hard quoted. In `jq`, you can use string interpolation `"Addr \($ad)"`, or concatenation (as above), which I find slightly more readable.

Comment: @ikegami yes I suppose "must not be quoted" isn't the most accurate way to describe it. Edited accordingly. I find the `+` syntax slightly more readable here.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for your suggestion. I gave some thought to cleanup and did so. To be clear, I think it good practice to avoid shell expansion in a `jq` command string, if features like `--arg, --argjson`, etc can be used instead.

Comment: Re "*I think it good practice to avoid shell expansion in a jq command string,*", 100%! One should never generate jq code (or Perl code, or ...) from the shell. Using --arg (or similar) or the environment is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

In [the `jq` manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual), search for "String interpolation"

```sh
jq --arg ad "192.168.5.5" -r '.name = "Addr \($ad)"'
```

Comment: I like this method better, but the other answer worked and he answered first. Also, I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation points yet.....